# How to get APN Name

Tags: android, gprs

I am using Android Phone for my Application Development. Here I am using `GPRS` to access the `Internet Connection`. Now My Question is how can I detect the Current `APN Name` that I am using for `GPRS Access` ? I know how to see `APN Name` in device, My Question is how to detect `APN Name` using coding ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out [Managing APN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zhengpei/archive/2009/10/13/managing-apn-data-in-google-android.aspx)

And See the Stackoverflow link  [Access Point Name with code,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257567/create-network-access-point-name-with-code)