# preferred default APN behavior on Android

Tags: android, 3g, android-2.2-froyo, gprs, apn

We can create a custom APN and make it default as written in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7928751/2935967) topic. But I'm not sure that default APN is used in 100% cases.

> 1. How can I gain confidence that my application uses default and only default APN and throws exception if it's unavailable?
> 2. Should I delete other APNs or is there any other way?

Thank you in advance!