# Android 4.2 and above read APN setting

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager, apn

I want to read APN settings on Android 4.2 and above. when of best answer i found on the link 
[stackoverflow reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453640/read-apns-in-android-4-2)

it works  most of android phone having os 4.2 and above.but does not work most of the samsung devices. Any other way to decide default APN settings?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8293171/2375207) seems to work, haven't exhaustively tested yet:

```
TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
answer = tel.getNetworkOperatorName(); //numeric: tel.getNetworkOperator();
```

May also check for

```
tel.getSimOperatorName();
```

Comment: this solution does not work on Android 4.2 and above.