# How should an Android carrier app create APNs?

Tags: android, apn

Given that you're a carrier app (defined by https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/carrier), what's the correct way to add APNs for devices on api 28 or higher?

The [Android documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/update) talks about how to submit AOSP patches to add your APNs to the AOSP codebase, but that's not really interesting for a carrier app.  (It's not that it's wrong, since a carrier often can and should do this.  It's just that the timeline isn't at all helpful; a carrier app needs to add APNs immediately, not years from now when the AOSP code makes it into shipping devices.)

There are questions from a long time ago (almost a decade for [Create Network Access Point Name with code,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257567/create-network-access-point-name-with-code)), but that can't be the modern way to do it, especially since there are now APIs like [ApnSetting.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/telephony/data/ApnSetting.Builder).

Answer (score 0):

Google responded to the bug I filed (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160269621) and updated the documention.  It now covers adding an APN (https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/carrier#adding_apn):

> Adding APNs with a carrier app To add APNs programmatically from a
> carrier app (for example, during SIM activation), use ContentResolver
> APIs to add APN items to a content provider identified by the URI
> android.provider.Telephony.Carriers.CONTENT_URI. For more information
> about the table structure for the content URI, see Telephony.Carriers.
>
> For more information, see APN and CarrierConfig.